# Change Expandable List direction

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview, android-theme, expandablelistadapter

At the moment, my expandedable list starts at the bottom, so it looks like this:

```
------------------------------
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|^ Item 1                    |
|    Item 1.1                |
|    Item 1.2                |
|    Item 1.3                |
|v Item 2                    |
|v Item 3                    |
|v Item 4                    |
------------------------------
```

Is there any way to make it start from the top, rather than the bottom? Or is this because I chose the Holo-Light theme?

```
------------------------------
|^ Item 1                    |
|    Item 1.1                |
|    Item 1.2                |
|    Item 1.3                |
|v Item 2                    |
|v Item 3                    |
|v Item 4                    |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
-----------------------------
```

Main Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.wdi.wdigateway.CustomizeGatewayActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/components"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/done"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Parent View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Child View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you put `android:layout_above="@+id/done"` without specifying the top alignment. I assume there is another view called `done` down there.

To force the list to display on the top, put also `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`.

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/components"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/done"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
</ExpandableListView>
```